# How can I get the index of features for each score of rfecv?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I am useing recursive feature elimination and cross-validated (rfecv) in order to find the best accuracy score for features.
As I see _grid_scoresis the score the estimator produced when trained with the i-th subset of features. Is there any way to get the index of subset features for each score in the _grid_score?
I can get the index of the selected features for highest score using get_support ( 5 subset of features).

subset_features, scores

5 , 0.976251

4 , 0.9762072

3 , 0.97322212

How can I get the indexes of 4 or 3 subset of features?
I checked the output of rfecv.ranking_ and the  5 features have rank =1 , but the Rank= 2 only has one feature and so on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (single) subset of 3 (or 4) features was (probably) never chosen!

This seems to be a common misconception on how `RFECV` works; see [How does cross-validated recursive feature elimination drop features in each iteration (sklearn RFECV)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65554133/10495893).  There's an `RFE` for each cross-validation fold (say 5), and each will produce its own set of 3 features (probably different).  Unfortunately (in this case at least), those `RFE` objects are not saved, so you cannot identify which sets of features each fold has selected; only the score is saved (source [pt1](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed55847ee70d363bdbfe14ee4401438fba057/sklearn/feature_selection/_rfe.py#L605), [pt2](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed55847ee70d363bdbfe14ee4401438fba057/sklearn/feature_selection/_rfe.py#L31)) for choosing the optimal number of features, and then another `RFE` is trained on the entire dataset to reduce to the final set of features.