# How does scikit's RFECV class compute cv_results_?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

**My understanding of Recursive Feature Elimination Cross Validation:** (`sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV`) You provide an algorithm which is trained on the entire dataset and creates a feature importance ranking using attributes `coef_` or `feature_importances_`. Now with all features included, this algorithm is evaluated by cross validation. Then the feature ranked at the bottom is removed and the model is retrained on the dataset and creates a new ranking, once again assessed by cross validation. This continues until all but one feature remain (or as specified by `min_features_to_select`), and the final number of features chosen depends on what yielded the highest CV score. ([Source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py))

**Question:** The CV score for each number of features is stored in `rfecv.cv_results_["mean_test_score"]`, and I've been facing trouble trying to replicate these scores without using scikit's built in method.

This is what I have tried to obtain the score for n-1 features, where n is the total number of features.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV

alg = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 0)
cv_split = StratifiedKFold(5)
# train is a pandas dataframe, x_var and y_var are both lists containing variable strings
X = train[x_var]
y = np.ravel(train[y_var])

alg.fit(X, y)
lowest_ranked_feature = np.argmin(alg.feature_importances_)
x_var.pop(lowest_ranked_feature)

one_removed_feature = train[x_var]
alg.fit(one_removed_feature, y)
cv_score = cross_validate(alg, one_removed_feature, y, cv=cv_split, scoring="accuracy")
np.mean(cv_score["test_score"])
```

And this is the inbuilt method that provides a different score:

```
rfecv = RFECV(
    estimator=alg,
    step=1,
    cv=cv_split,
    scoring="accuracy",
)

rfecv.fit(X, y)
rfecv.cv_results_["mean_test_score"][-2]
```

**How do I get the exact scores as calculated in the inbuilt method?**

I would also like to mention that I did try this first with all n features, and my method matched with
`rfecv.cv_results_["mean_test_score"][-1]`.

Comment: Your description is not how `RFECV` works. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/65554133/10495893 and its linked questions.

Comment: I see this is a common misconception of RFECV. Could you check this explanation @BenReiniger? Cross validation is not implemented at each step within RFE, but rather RFE is implemented within each fold of cross validation: 

CV is used once at the start using the entire dataset. For each fold fit the model to the train split and score it on the test split with the specified metric. Then remove the least important feat (through feat importance) and repeat the evaluation n times, returning the array- number of feats vs score. After aggregating over folds, RFECV chooses highest number of feats.

Comment: that's it!  ("highest _scoring_ number of feats", of course)

Comment: That link as well as the GitHub discussion forums helped me understand how RFECV works thanks! However, I think this question is still worth answering as my code provided was built upon an incorrect understanding of RFECV. I will revise the code and answer my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Ben, the reason you are finding different answers is because your understanding of RFECV is fundamentally flawed. Cross validation is not implemented at each step within RFE, but rather RFE is implemented within each fold of cross validation.

Your method currently removes a feature from the data and then performs CV to score it, and essentially performs a different CV to score each subset of features. However, RFECV performs CV only a single time at the start, and then cycles between removing a feature and scoring the model **within** a singular fold.

*Note: From experimentation, I have found that sklearn RFECV computes the score on a singular fold directly by using whichever evaluation metric you specify, and not another layer of cross validation or anything. In your case, you have chosen `scoring="accuracy"`. So within a fold, the model will score the test split based on accuracy, and repeat this for each subset of features.*

**You can implement RFECV from scratch as follows:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def score(alg, x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test):
    """Calculate the accuracy score of the algorithm."""
    alg.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = alg.predict(x_test)
    return accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

def rfecv_function(alg, x_var, X, y, cv):
    """Perform RFECV and return a dictionary to store an array of test scores
    for each cv, where the array contains test scores for each number of 
    features selected 1,2,...,n (n is total number of features).
    """
    dic = {}
    # Iterate through folds
    for fold_index, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(cv.split(X, y)):
        x_train_fold, y_train_fold = X.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[train_index]
        x_test_fold, y_test_fold = X.iloc[test_index], y.iloc[test_index]
        features = x_var.copy()
        
        # Array to store test scores for each feature subset
        scores_array = np.empty(len(x_var))
        
        # Iterate through the feature subsets
        for i in range(len(x_var)):
            # Calculate and store the scores in the array
            scores = score(alg, x_train_fold[features], y_train_fold, 
                           x_test_fold[features], y_test_fold)
            scores_array[-i-1] = scores 
            # Find and remove the lowest ranked feature
            alg.fit(x_train_fold[features], y_train_fold)
            lowest_rank = features[np.argmin(alg.feature_importances_)]
            features.remove(lowest_rank)
            
        dic[f"split{fold_index}_test_score"] = scores_array
    
    return dic

dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 0)
cv_split = StratifiedKFold(5, shuffle=True, random_state=0)

# Assume train is a pandas dataframe
x_var = ["var1", "var2", "var3"]
y_var = ["target_var"]
rfecv_scores = rfecv_function(dtree, x_var, train[x_var], train[y_var], cv_split)
```

The `rfecv_scores` provide identical values to those computed in the inbuilt class `RFECV.cv_results_`